# Perform calculation based on a Group By column and then I have to pass that value to a new column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
id  numerator denominator 
1     1          2
1     5          6
1     8          9
2     4          6
3     8          9
3     2          5
```

1st groupby based on id

```
id  numerator denominator
1     14          17
2      4           6
3     10          14
```

Final calculation on the same df

```
id  numerator denominator ratio
1     1          2        14/17
1     5          6        14/17
1     8          9        14/17
2     4          6         4/6
3     8          9        10/14
3     2          5        10/14
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['ratio'] = df.groupby('id').transform('sum').eval('numerator/denominator')
print (df)
   id  numerator  denominator     ratio
0   1          1            2  0.823529
1   1          5            6  0.823529
2   1          8            9  0.823529
3   2          4            6  0.666667
4   3          8            9  0.714286
5   3          2            5  0.714286
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael Instead of Df1 i want the task to be done by the use of function,I have to pass my df into a function and i need the columns to be added in the same dataframe

Comment: column names are mentioned as id,numerator,denominator

Comment: I dont want the concept of introducing another Dataframe,i want all the operations to be done on same dataframe please let me know Thank you ...

Comment: @rakesh - So need another answer? Not new column?

Comment: This is more than enough and it is more efficient.Thank you..

Comment: Oops didn't reallize op wanted to keep the original shape, nice answr

Comment: @jezrael I need the count of id after grouping that,I have tried df.groupby(by='Id').count() but it brings the total dataframe structure

Comment: @rakesh - Do you want `df.groupby(by='Id').size()` ?

Comment: @jezrael I want the exact count ie 3 as per the above example

Comment: df.groupby(by='Id').size() this will gives the output as Length: 1396, dtype: int64